# How to fork Ethereum(go implementation) to make a new chain?

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to fork Ethereum(go implementation) to make another new public chain which should start again from the block zero but keeping all other parameters same as in main chain. Please guide me with all the steps to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new chain is not that simple.
You have to create your own genesis block that will contain the initial informations of your blockchain.
Then you will need peers that have geth nodes initialized with the same genesis block.
So you must make them connect together, and find new clients when they connect.
Ethereum uses bootnodes, special static nodes that will guide tou during your network discovery.

These bootnodes allow peers to find initial peers very easily, and I dout you can do anything without them.